Unable to make out this cryptic unicode characters resulting from R strsplit
I get email junk with subject line such as this, and am trying to figure out what this encoding and code is. Any idea? I want to put the proper spam filter, but not sure what the rule should include as for subject line filtering given the following.
strsplit('Veterans: Unlock the Best Auto Insurance Deals Now­­­­', '')
[[1]]
  [1] "\U{0e001d}" "V"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "e"          "\U{0e001d}" "t"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}"
 [11] "\U{0e001d}" "e"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "r"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "a"          "\U{0e001d}" "n"         
 [21] "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "s"          ":"          " "          "\U{0e001d}" "U"          "n"          "\U{0e001d}" "l"         
 [31] "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "o"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "c"          "\U{0e001d}" "k"          "\U{0e001d}"
 [41] "\U{0e001d}" " "          "\U{0e001d}" "t"          "h"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "e"          " "         
 [51] "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "B"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "e"         
 [61] "\U{0e001d}" "s"          "t"          "\U{0e001d}" " "          "A"          "\U{0e001d}" "u"          "\U{0e001d}" "t"         
 [71] "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "o"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" " "          "I"          "n"          "\U{0e001d}"
 [81] "s"          "u"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "r"          "a"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "n"          "c"         
 [91] "\U{0e001d}" "e"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" " "          "\U{0e001d}" "D"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" "e"         
[101] "a"          "\U{0e001d}" "l"          "\U{0e001d}" "s"          "\U{0e001d}" "\U{0e001d}" " "          "\U{0e001d}" "N"         
[111] "\U{0e001d}" "o"          "w"          "­"          "­"          "­"          "­"         


\U{0e001d} is from Unicode's Private Use Area . So the spam text pads each word with a bunch of characters that are not assigned to a glyph and will generally not be printed. To pick this up, you could add a filter for characters in the range U+E000..U+F8FF. There might be some false positives though - it would be worth looking for such characters in emails you know are legit to see whether they sometimes turn up for some reason, and perhaps use such a rule with a minimum threshold or other heuristics.
